# How to debug SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I don't know what's going on.

After sending the **show_prizes** request.

I got the expected result  and also got the error exception

And  Rails server **can not** accept  request anymore.

I'm totally not knowing what happened

#### view

```
  - @prizes.each do |prize|
    %tr
      %td.center= prize.id
      %td.center
        = prize.name
```

#### controller

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  def show_prizes
    if params.has_key? :page 
      prizes = Prize.unscoped.sort(_id: 1).to_a.flatten
      @prizes = Kaminari.paginate_array(prizes).page(params[:page]).per(20)
    else
      prizes = Prize.unscoped.sort(_id: 1).to_a.flatten
      @prizes = Kaminari.paginate_array(prizes).page(1).per(20)
    end
  end
end
```

#### console

```
Started GET "/dashboard/show_prizes" for ::1 at 2015-01-14 13:06:41 +0800
Processing by DashboardController#show_prizes as HTML
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 1.4210ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=vivo_lottery_development collection=prizes selector={"$query"=>{}, "$orderby"=>{"_id"=>1}} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 7.0220ms
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 GET_MORE     database=vivo_lottery_development collection=prizes limit=0 cursor_id=117556587723 runtime: 15.1670ms
  Rendered dashboard/show_prizes.html.haml within layouts/application (6.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 262ms (Views: 206.9ms)
[2015-01-14 13:06:42] ERROR SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    /.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:159
[2015-01-14 13:06:42] ERROR SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    /.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is going to be enabling some sort of low-level Ruby call logging, sorta like:

```
$call_log_enabled = false
$call_log = open('call_log.txt', 'w')

set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  if event == 'call' && $call_log_enabled
    $call_log.puts "#{file}:#{line} #{classname}##{id}"
  end
}
```

Then, whenever you need to turn on the tracing, just modify the global variable:

```
$call_log_enabled = true
```

Also, if you are suddenly getting a SystemStackError in a Rails Application and are using `alias_method_chain` then class reloading in development mode can cause this error.  In that case, you can wrap your logic in

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
   ...
end
```

The code in the to_prepare block will not run on every development request.